# Fatal Error - Fatal error: Unsupported operand types in public_html/includes/common.inc on line 2999

Tags: blocks

The page of my work is not loading anymore!
And Im not used to deal with drupal!
What I have to do to the page load properly! I even cant login as user or see any page of the site!
PLZ im really desesperated!

this error show when i try to enter in the page:
Fatal error: Unsupported operand types in /home/storage/2/58/58/xxxxx/public_html/includes/common.inc on line 2999
the page i wanna to work is that: www.meddco.com.br!

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers. Could you please provide more information about your issue and improve your question, thank you.

Comment: i dont know what is happening......i just cant access the site anymore!

Comment: the last think i did was try to put a new form with php......and before it everthing was crashed!

Comment: is this a custom module that you added the form with .  if so are you using drush .  As I would disable (dis) the module using drush if it where me.

Comment: how can i do it? im a newbie in drupal!

Comment: @Meddco you need to provide more information otherwise we cannot help you. Please re-edit the question and add details such as what you did before this issue, what kind of form is this (is it a custom module?) or where you placed the piece of code (some PHP field?) etc.

Comment: Actually i placed the code in "text" field and put php filtered! i cant give more details cause i have not more access at page or main page or user page and admin page!

Comment: i did this edit when im create a new block

Comment: Do you have access to the database? Phpmyadmin or something?

Comment: Yes,  I have access!

Answer (score 0):

You need to access the installation's database.

- Find the 'block_custom' table. This contains all custom blocks.
- Browse the records and locate the one which creates the problem.
- Clear the field 'body' which should contain your custom PHP code.

Comment: ok! im in database! i found just blocks / blocks_roles /
cache_block and  multiblock!

Comment: how i find "body" in this lines! im dont have any experience in DB!

Comment: Man! I think I resolved.....i didnt find the "body" but found the blocks with the name i did put when setting! Now i have access back!

Comment: u saved my life and my job!

Comment: Where did you find them? If the answer satisfied your question mark it as accepted, and I would recommend you to modify your original post to form a proper question that could help other users as well.